# Manhwa where female protagonist tries to escape death after reincarnating several times in a fantasy/historical novel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, isekai

I am looking for a full color manhwa.

A girl reincarnates into a novel(?) and realizes that she dies after some number of years. She tries to avoid that and takes a different route but dies anyways. After she dies she gets teleported back in time and she tries again with a different route. I think in the first chapters it is introduced that she tries different life paths eg. as a merchant, next time as a soldier, and so on. When she starts the cycle I think she is 16-18.

The story begins after she has gone through multiple lives. She doesn't die mid-manhwa I think. Setting is fantasy/historical.

That is all I know :(

Comment: You say manhwa, so this is a full-color longstrip webtoon, correct? You're uncertain that the main character reincarnated into a novel, but are you positive that she lived outside the story and reincarnated in? i.e. it's definitely not same-world reincarnation? Do you remember how old she is at the start of each reincarnation, or the color of her hair? She dies multiple times before the manhwa itself starts - do you recall if she dies mid-manhwa and has to start over?

Comment: Yeah its full color and when she starts the cycle i think 16-18 maybe. I think in the first chapters it is introduced that she tries different life paths eg.  as a Merchant  next time as a soldier and so on. No she dont't dies mid manhwa i think

Comment: This isn't full color, so it probably isn't it, but it's similar enough that it's worth ruling out: "7th Time Loop: The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy!". Not this, correct?

Comment: Sadly no but the story seems interesting thank you for the tip. I rember in on life she where the wife of a pirate of an small island.

Comment: What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: Dont know the Hair color anymore :(

Comment: There's a "time loop" tag on mangaupdates, and not very many uses, but none of them seem like a good match. In most cases the heroine keeps the same setting for her other lives. Is the female MC definitely the one dying, and not her brother (Touch My Little Brother and You're Dead)? How do you know the pirate she married was a pirate? Do you recall what he looked like? Is just running off and marrying someone else enough (The Broken Ring)? Do you remember any specifics of her deaths?

Comment: I dont know if it is related to the manhwa or its another. But she is married to a duke who is task to defend the empire from monsters. The territory is snowcovery and cold an on one point of the story she gets kidnapped from his castle.

Comment: "Another typical fantasy romance"? Duke; Snow covered; fights monsters; she's reincarnated in a story. Only a single time rewind, she's an empress in her first story life, not a merchant (she's dressed like a fancy soldier, I guess). She isn't aware she'll be killed, she dies unexpectedly. Probably unrelated to the question. The only other story I recall with the snowy duke setup is "Author of my own destiny", but that doesn't have time travel at all.

Answer (score 0):

FRIEND IVE BEEN LOOK FOR IT FOR OVER AN HOUR BUT I FOUND IT. It’s “Resetting Lady” I hope this is the one you’ve been looking for cuz it sure is the one I have.

Comment: Could you edit this to explain how _Resetting Lady_ matches the description given in the question? It'd help other users decide how likely it is to be the correct answer.

Comment: [Resetting lady was first published Aug 7, 2022](https://myanimelist.net/manga/151065/The_Crimson_Lady), two days after the question was asked.